# TypeError: string indices must be integers - while trying to read secret

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-keyvault

I try to read the value of my secret, which is in Azure key vault. To achieve this aim I try this code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault-secrets/azure.keyvault.secrets.secretclient?view=azure-python#azure-keyvault-secrets-secretclient-get-secret):

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

# Create a SecretClient using default Azure credentials
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url, credential)
secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name)
print(secret.value)
```

but after running this I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tefadm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 128, in __next__
    return next(self._page_iterator)
  File "C:\Users\tefadm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 76, in __next__
    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
  File "C:\Users\tefadm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\keyvault\secrets\_generated\v7_3\operations\_key_vault_client_operations.py", line 798, in get_next
    map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
  File "C:\Users\tefadm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\core\exceptions.py", line 106, in map_error
    error = error_type(response=response)
  File "C:\Users\tefadm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\keyvault\secrets\_shared\exceptions.py", line 24, in _get_exception_for_key_vault_error
    message = "({}) {}".format(body["error"]["code"], body["error"]["message"])  # type: Optional[str]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Do you have any idea, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried in my environment and got suuceessfully retrieved secret by same code.***

```
from  azure.keyvault.secrets  import  SecretClient
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential
keyVaultName = ["<vault name>"]
KVUri = f"https://{Vault name}.vault.azure.net"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
secret= secret_client.get_secret("secret2")#secretname
print(secret.value)
```

In my keyvault I have one secret kindly see my below snap:

[image]

> `python TypeError: string indices must be integers`

The above error may cause whether you have passing keyvault name instead of secret name.

Now I tried your code and got an successfull output, which has retrieved the secrets from keyvault.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what was my problem. I try to retrieve a Key with this function and not a secret. There is a difference between both.  Do you have any idea how can I retrieve Key content, and not the JsonWebKey from azure key vault?